# ang2/bootstrap - capture and defeat browser's datepicker popup on input type=date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, datepicker

ngx-bootstrap does not support a popup datepicker, so I'm trying to make my own.

I've started with input type="date" - I like the default '3 fields' behavior because it enforces value-constraints and format integrity. But I want to add my own datepicker popup to its onclick.

**How can I capture and defeat* the browser's native datepicker popup, so I can add my own?**

*without killing onclick and keyboard control completely

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="date" (click)="toto($event)">

toto(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   ....
}
```

Comment: Huh. I thought that would have killed *all* events (such as the spinner and the partial field focusing), but it does not seem to. Thanks!